# Keyboard shortcut unintentionally triggering Java's UndoManager undo function

Tags: java, swing, undo

I have set up my application so that when I press Ctrl+Z, my UndoManager will undo the last entry. However, for some reason, Ctrl+H will also do this, and I have no idea why.

[Here is my source code.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwycqobtom1mc9l/TextEditor.java?dl=0)

Comment: In the future, post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code in your question, not in drop box.

Comment: Got it! Not a very frequent user here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I press Ctrl+Z, my UndoManager will undo the last entry. However, for some reason, Ctrl+H will also do this,

Ctrl+H is not invoking your UndoManager.

Ctrl+H, is a Key Binding to delete the previous character in a text component.

This is easy to test. Just type some text into the text component. Then set the caret to a different position in the text component. The character deleted will be the character at the current caret position, not the last character typed into the text component.

You can check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a program that displays all the default Key Bindings for a given component.